# Google App Engine Node Task Queue Retries before Finished

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am running a slow operation via a cloud task queue to delete objects from Google Cloud Storage. I have noticed that the task queue retries the task after two minutes have passed, even though the running task is not yet finished nor errored.

What is the best strategy to trigger valid retries, but not retry while the task is still running?

Here's my task creator:

```
router.get('/start-delete-old', async (req, res) => {
  const task = {
    appEngineHttpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      relativeUri: `/videos/delete-old`,
    },
  };

  const request = {
    parent: taskClient.parent,
    task: task,
  };

  const [response] = await taskClient.queue.createTask(request);
  res.send(response);
});
```

Here's my task handler:

```
router.post('/delete-old', async (req, res) => {
  let cameras = await knex('cameras')
  let date = moment().subtract(365, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  for (let i = 0; i < cameras.length; i++) {
    let camera = cameras[i]
    let prefix = `${camera.id}/${date}/`
    try {
      await bucket.deleteFiles({ prefix: prefix, force: true })
      await knex.raw(`delete from videos where camera_id = ${camera.id} and cast(start_time as date) = '${date}'`)
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log('error deleting ' + e)
    }
  }
  res.send({});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, a [timeout](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers#timeouts) in a task can vary depending on the environment you are using:

### Standard environment

- Automatic scaling: task processing must finish in 10 minutes.
- Manual and basic scaling: requests can run up to 24 hours.

### Flexible environment

- For worker services running in the flex environment: all types have a 60 minute timeout.

So, if your handler misses the deadline, the queue assumes the task failed and retries it.

Also, the Task Queue is expecting to receive an status code between 200 and 299, if not, it will assume that the running task will fail. Quoting the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers):

> Upon successful completion of processing, the handler must send an HTTP status code between 200 and 299 back to the queue. Any other value indicates the task has failed and the queue retries the task.

I believe that both the bucket delete files and the knex raw query, are taking a lot of time to be processed, and this is causing the handler to return an status other than 200-299.

One good way to troubleshoot is using Stackdriver logs, you will be able to gather more information about the ongoing processes and see if any of them is returning any error.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read that documentation and the task is restarting exactly after 2 minutes (prior to any response being sent). I confirmed that by looking at the stackdriver logs. The 2 minute deadline is the part that I have not found any documentation for.

Comment: @user1527312 Thanks for the reply! Then that is surely something not expected, to be able to further assist you, could you please create an issue in the following [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=608795&template=1251543). This link will be only visible to you and people from Google, so don't worry about sharing your project ID there.